# How to get a function call to wait till another one is finished

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, callback, underscore.js

So what I want is,

```
functionA(); // this completes 
functionB(); // then this runs
```

Im trying to seed multiple collections into a database in one go, and when I've procedurally put each collection after each other only the last one is seeded into the database. I'm trying to figure-out how to keep Javascript from being Asynchronous, so I can have each step wait till the previous one is done. I feel like I could use Underscores "defer" method, which Defers invoking the function until the current call stack has cleared; I just don't know how to use it.

I"m using underscores delay method, and that works but its dependent on the seed sizes and I want to get away from that.

The code looks like this:

```
// creates and sends seed data to a collecion("blah") inside a db("heroes")
var blog = MeanSeed.init("heroes", "blah");
blog.exportToDB();

// this waits a second till it starts seeding the "heroes" DB with its "aliens" collection
_.delay(function() {
  var user = MeanSeed.init("heroes", "aliens");   
  user.exportToDB();  
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). It's pretty new and it was introduced in ES6 (but it's already in Node 5-6). An example for usage:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    // do something in A
    resolve();
}).then(function(result) {
    // do something else in B
    return result;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a callback function, like this:

```
function functionA(done){
    //do some stuff
    done(true);
}
function functionB(){

}

functionA(function(success){
    if(success)
        functionB();
});
```

Or, you can use promises.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, callbacks are a mind warp, but they're cool